# mysqli_stmt::bind_param() error: query with join

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, bindparam

I have a code for form that gets information from database, based on id of city(idci). I want to update the information using this form, but I get this error  message:

> mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of
>   parameters in prepared statement

queries work fine, i checked them in phpmyadmin sql imput.

if in $query i leave only "select idci" or "select *", I can see in the form correct id for city(idci), but the rest fields are empty.

if $query is the way it is written in the code example, I get information in the form for 1st result in the table, instead of the chosen result to edit.

Thanks for any help!

```
isset($_GET['idci']) ? $idci=$_GET['idci'] : $idci='';
isset($_GET['nameci']) ? $nameci=$_GET['nameci'] : $nameci='';
isset($_GET['nameco']) ? $nameco=$_GET['nameco'] : $nameco='';
isset($_GET['idco']) ? $idco=$_GET['idco'] : $idco='';
isset($_GET['submit']) ? $submit=true : $submit=false;


if(!$submit){
$query = "select idci, nameci, nameco, idco
        from city 
        JOIN country on country.idco=city.country_idco 
        ";
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query))
{
$stmt-> bind_param('i', $idci);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($idci, $nameci, $nameco, $idco);
$stmt->fetch();

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();

echo'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>h1{color:red;}label{color:darkred;}</style>
<title>Edit user</title>
<meta charset=”UTF-8”>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Edit city:</h1>
<form action="" method="GET">
<label>cityID </label><input readonly name="idci" value="'.$idci.'"><br>
<label>city </label><input type="text" name="nameci" value="'.$nameci.'"><br>
<label>country </label><input type="text" name="nameco" value="'.$nameco.'"><br>
<label>countryID </label><input readonly name="idci" value="'.$idco.'"><br>

<input type=reset value=Clear>
<input type=submit value=Edit name=submit></form>

</body>
</html>
';
}
}else{
$query1 = "
            UPDATE city 
            JOIN country
            ON city.country_idco=country.idco
            SET city.nameci =?, country.nameco=?
            WHERE idci = ?";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query1))
{

$stmt->bind_param('ssii', $nameci, $nameco, $idco, $idci);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: you don't have a `WHERE` clause or any `?` to bind a param (called $idci) in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has no placeholders, period. So there's NOTHING for `bindParam()` to operate on, and you get that exact error message:

```
$query = "select idci, nameci, nameco, idco
        from city 
        JOIN country on country.idco=city.country_idco 
        ";
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query))
{
$stmt-> bind_param('i', $idci);
                    ^---one parameter to bind, but absolutely NO ? in the query.
```

Comment: oh, i see!
just had to add "where idci=?" in the end of query.
Thanks, it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

could be you  have more params in update  .. you have only 3 ? in update but 4 param in bind_

```
 $query1 = "
        UPDATE city 
        JOIN country
        ON city.country_idco=country.idco
        SET city.nameci =?, country.nameco=?
        WHERE idci = ?";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query1))
{

 $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $nameci, $nameco, /*   this in not in update $idco , */ $idci);
```

Comment: added idco in query, same result.
cut out idco from bind_param like you show, same error :\

Comment: Be sure you have the same number and type you declared .. and eventually show the new query you used ..

Comment: it's fixed now, another user's advice helped. thanks anyway :)